# Advertisment insertions in new azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azureportal

Need to configure Advertisement Insertions and Slate Images in the new Azure portal using live encoding type of Live streaming channel. Kindly help on this as i am unable to find the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Ad insertions options for azure media services are described here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-inserting-ads-on-client-side/

"Azure Media Services provides support for ad insertion through the Windows Media Platform: Player Frameworks. Player frameworks with ad support are available for Windows 8, Silverlight, Windows Phone 8, and iOS devices."

Per Azure media Services Player documentation (https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/Features.html) , Ad insertion is not supported yet at AMS player level.